# Problems with SlidingMenu library

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to make a shadow in my entire activity, like the commonly used in tutorials of how to use some app, but I don't know any way to do this.
If you want more details about why I want to do this, I'll explain:

- I found an old app at my works GitLab, but it was made before the oficial implementation of NavigationDrawer. So, it uses a library called "SlidingMenu" (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), but this library is very limited and I don't have any idea of how to make the activity look "disabled" while the sliding menu is open.
  By the way, if someone knows how to set a maxWidth to the sliding menu please feel free to tell me because i don't.

Comment: Why don't you just modify it to use `DrawerLayout` instead?

Comment: Lol, I forgot about it. I'll try it with a BaseActivity. Thanks.